# Error Accessing S3 bucket through Lambda function despite permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I created a lambda function which gets invoked on file upload to an S3 bucket. The function then scans the file and outputs the result in Cloudwatch. When I deploy the exact same infrastructure using Cloudformation template, I get an error :

```
[ERROR] ClientError: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden
```

The only difference between my trial and Cloudformation is that I am generating the bucket name dynamically in the template. Other than that, everything is the same. I am attaching the exact same permissions to the lambda function through CFN which would otherwise work in my testing.

I tried some of the other solutions mentioned where people fixed their system clock issue to get this working.
I am doing everything through the UI and not using CLI.

My cloudformation template is uploaded [here](https://github.com/abhinavbom/clara/blob/master/diff.yaml):

Can anyone help me solve this mystery. I am having a real tough time digging into this.

Comment: Can you confirm how the S3 bucket name is being passed into your Lambda function? From what I see you upload a zip but there is no environment variable pasting this name. Without seeing the Lambda it is a missing part of the puzzle :(

Comment: @ChrisWilliams I am adding S3 trigger manually to the lambda function and specify the S3 bucket I want to extract the file from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `IAMManagedPolicy` is incorrect. Statements such as:

```
arn:aws:s3:::{$S3Bucket}/*
```

will not resolve to your bucket's name, as you are missing [Sub](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html) and the syntax is incorrect.

You can try the following (`Sub` and `${S3Bucket}` added):

```
IAMManagedPolicy:
        Type: "AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy"
        Properties:
            ManagedPolicyName: "bucket-scan-policy-2"
            Path: "/"
            PolicyDocument: !Sub |
                {
                    "Version": "2012-10-17",
                    "Statement": [
                        {
                            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
                            "Effect": "Allow",
                            "Action": [
                                "s3:GetObject",
                                "sns:Publish",
                                "kms:Decrypt",
                                "s3:PutObjectVersionTagging",
                                "s3:GetObjectTagging",
                                "s3:PutObjectTagging"
                            ],
                            "Resource": [
                                "arn:aws:sns:::<av-scan-start>",
                                "arn:aws:sns:::<av-status>",
                                "arn:aws:s3:::${S3Bucket}/*"
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
                            "Effect": "Allow",
                            "Action": [
                                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                                "logs:PutLogEvents"
                            ],
                            "Resource": "*"
                        },
                        {
                            "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
                            "Effect": "Allow",
                            "Action": "s3:*",
                            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::yara-rules/*"
                        },
                        {
                            "Sid": "VisualEditor3",
                            "Effect": "Allow",
                            "Action": "s3:*",
                            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::${S3Bucket}/*"
                        },
                        {
                            "Sid": "VisualEditor9",
                            "Effect": "Allow",
                            "Action": "s3:*",
                            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::${S3Bucket}"
                        },
                        {
                            "Sid": "VisualEditor4",
                            "Effect": "Allow",
                            "Action": "s3:*",
                            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::yara-rules"
                        }
                    ]
                }
```

Comment: Thanks that was helpful. I made the changes and it worked.